# Refresh lwc without button click or reload of page when a different record is updated

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, refreshapex

I have the following lwc, `myComponent` that will query related objects and display some fields when someone visits the record page of the Account record. I want to refresh the data without the click of a button or page reloading as soon as the related object is updated.

**Question**

1. How can I refresh the data from a lightning record page when a related object is updated without a button click or page reload?

**current code**

`myComponent.js`

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import getRecordsMethod from '@salesforce/apex/MyController.getRecords';

export default class MyComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
  @api myRecord;

  @wire(getRecordsMethod)
  wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    if(error) { // error code }
    else if(data) { this.myRecord = data; }

   /** how do we refresh this.myRecord? **/
  }
  handleOnClick(event) {
    /* refreshApex(this.wiredRecord); */

    /* this also didn't work */
    // refreshApex(this.myRecord);
  }
}
```

`MyController.getRecords`

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Account> getRecords() {
  return [SELECT Id, Name,
                 (SELECT Id, Name, MyField_to_Update__c
                  FROM Opportunities),
                 (SELECT Id, Name, Field_updated__c
                  FROM Contacts)
          From Account
          LIMIT 10];
}
```

`MyComponent.hmtl`

```
<template>
  <template if:true={wiredRecord.data}>
        <template for:each={wiredRecord.data} for:item="accnt" for:index="idx">
            <div key={accnt.Id} class="slds-m-bottom_medium">
                <p>{accnt.Name}</p>
                <p>{accnt.MyField_to_Update__c}</p> 
            </div>
        </template>
        <!-- Click the button to render -->
        <lightning-button label="rerender" onclick={handleOnClick}></lightning-button>
    </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make your component [context-aware](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_record_context):

```
export default class MyComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
  @api recordId; // Provided by the runtime
  @wire(getRecordsMethod, { accountId: '$recordId' }) account; // reactive
```

And in your Apex, just pass in the record Id:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Account> getRecords(Id recordId) {
  return [SELECT Id, Name,
           (SELECT Id, Name, MyField_to_Update__c
             FROM Opportunities),
           (SELECT Id, Name, Field_updated__c
             FROM Contacts)
          From Account WHERE Id = :recordId];
}
```

Comment: would I reference `account` variable in my HTML file then?

Comment: Use `{account.data.Field}` as needed.

Comment: I want to clarify something for me in this answer. Will it solve the question "refresh the data from a lightning record page when a related object is updated without a button click or page reload" ?

Comment: @VitaliiDehnerys When the record changes (e.g. a new account is in view) or when Lightning Data Service detects changes in data, it should refresh.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification.

Comment: @sfdcfox unfortunately it does not work to refresh as data is updated. I added what i tried in the description of the question. I even tried `refreshApex` and it didn't work, no error is returned. Any other ideas?

Comment: @PhilW i am not able to use `{account.data.Field}` as I get an error indicating i cannot reference `myfield` from undefined variable meaning `account.data` is not defined. any ideas on how to display?

Comment: Do you want to update your component or also the record0age the component sits on?

Comment: @userRR just the component and render the latest data

Comment: @usernameabc You need to wait until the data is loaded. That's usually written as `if:true={account.data}`.

Comment: What sfdcfox says, in your template in the html file check if account.data is true

Another option is to declare a vari
able for your data in your JS file and write the wire like this

@wire(getRecordsMethod, { accountId: '$recordId' })
getRecordFunction({error, data}){
if(data) {
console.log(data) 
this.YOURVARIABLE = data.XXXXX
}
}

<< This way you are using a function to run after the @wire instead of straight assigning it to a variable